# Is it possible, to call cucumber from a method in Selenium Java and TestNG?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cross-browser, testng, cucumber-jvm

I have a working system, that works perfect for parallel browser testing.
And I can do an other project where the cucumber scenarios working good. No I want to add them together. I copied a little code from my script. I call the @Test-s parallel with TestNG and Maven from CLI. 
I wrote a new line "CALLTHECUCUMBERSCENARIO(driver);" Where I want to call the Cucumber Scenario. Is it possible? 
Or how can I do this? Any idea?
If something missing let me now, and I write it here.
Thank you for your help. :)

```
@Test
    public void testChromeWin10() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        String chromeNodeWin10 = "http://192.168.0.175:5566/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(chromeNodeWin10), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Dimension d = new Dimension(1300,800);
        //Resize current window to the set dimension
        driver.manage().window().setSize(d);

        CALLTHECUCUMBERSCENARIO(driver);
    }


    @Test
    public void testFirefoxWin10() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        String firefoxNodeWin10 = "http://192.168.0.175:5577/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(firefoxNodeWin10), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(1300,1000);
        //Resize current window to the set dimension
        driver.manage().window().setSize(d);

        CALLTHECUCUMBERSCENARIO(driver);
    }


    @Test
    public void testEdgeWin10() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        String edgeNodeWin10 = "http://192.168.0.175:5588/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("MicrosoftEdge");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(edgeNodeWin10), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(1300,1000);
        //Resize current window to the set dimension
        driver.manage().window().setSize(d);

        CALLTHECUCUMBERSCENARIO(driver);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the Cucumber scenario from your code as you requested.

You will have to change how you are running your tests. You can run Cucumber scenarios with a Cucumber runner, where you can specify which scenarios to run.

To add Cucumber to your project, see [Cucumber docs - Installation](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/).

For how to use Cucumber and an example of the runner, see [Cucumber docs - 10 minute tutorial](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/).

For the tests you have written so far, you will need to split them into meaningful steps in feature files. In general, your setup (arrange) would be in "Given" steps, the action you are testing (act) in "When" steps, and your validation/verification of expected result (assert) in "Then" steps.

Each step you define will map to a (set of) actions/methods that set up the initial state (Given), perform the test (When) and verify the result (Then).

It is up to you to determine what meaningful steps are, and how to describe them in Scenarios/Examples that describe the intended behaviour of your system.

On how to write scenarios, please read: https://cucumber.io/docs/bdd/better-gherkin/

On how to implement, you might find the following pages helpful: 
* https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/ (in particular: https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/step-organization/)
* https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/ (in particular: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/ and https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/step-definitions/)

You will have to add additional setup to run them cross browser (I have no experience with that, so I cannot help you there).

Comment: Thanks, I could do this before. But Thank you for your help!